# Better to import more static data from Access, or to perform more calculations in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have an Excel 2010 file that imports tens of thousands of records from 5 tables in Access 2010 daily.

Let's say (for example) my Excel file needs 4 columns: CustomerID, TimeStamp, RegionID, and a combination of all three (for lookups).

Should I only have the combination column in Access, and then split out the three other columns from it in Excel (using formulas)?

Or should I bring in all 4 columns from Access, increasing the import size, but reducing the number of formula calculations on my large dataset?

Comment: Are you using a delimiting character?  If so you can bring it in and delimit it at the same time to reduce calculations

Comment: Any chance to leave Excel out? Either keep it completely in Access or (better) have some kind of SQL Server involved (at least Express).
Excel is not really suited well for "tens of thousands of records"

Comment: Probably sounds like a stupid answer, but the safest way to find out is to try it out. You got the data ...

Comment: @PWKad Can you import into Excel (into a Pivot, specifically) and delimit? Even if I could, though, I'd end up splitting my combo column into three, and still need to calculate the combo column again. Which would be the same as importing the three columns seperately, and creating the combo in Excel.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter No dice, it's a work project, and Excel was selected because of its familiarity with the end users.

Comment: @cars10 I hear you. I'm working on building the tool now, so I was hoping to pick a good direction first, rather than build it both ways and test. Always a fall back option, though.

Comment: This is just my local intranet, but I find that queries and imports take longer than calculations, ESPECIALLY if we have to query a database at another site.  It also depends on the specs of the users computer when it comes to calculations (though I'm sure you know that already).